# Yarn does not allow me to run scripts

Tags: javascript, package, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I have a problem with yarn. I am using Windows 10 PC and I installed yarn by `npm install -g yarn`. It was successful. But now when I try to add new script in any `package.json` file and run it I get:

[image]

What can be a problem here? I tried to reinstall yarn again globally but it didn't work. Should I add something to this `\AppData` folder?

Comment: Did you take a look inside the referenced folder? (it's hidden so you might have to turn hidden files visible in Explorer first, but you can also manually type it into the path field at the top). Also I had similar issues with Powershell and used cmd instead. Just type cmd to go to a command prompt instead and try yarn again.

Comment: I am using vs code command line

Comment: It's PowerShell, look at the `PS` at the start. Just type `cmd` and try again

Comment: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1526]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.` this is what I get after typing `cmd`

Comment: Yep, that's the command prompt. Now type `yarn run electron:serve`

Comment: yes and I get exactly same error as above

Comment: Can you post the "scripts" part of your package.json?

Comment: I opened another project where I have the same error and script that I try to use is `"deploy": "yarn build; gh-pages -d build",` so I run `yarn deploy` and I get the same error

Comment: Right, so I'll point you to my first comment again. You said you installed yarn globally, and it has to be for any of this to work but the fact that you say "I tried to reinstall yarn again globally but it didn't work" and the error message point to that not being the case. Still, it says "yarn run v1.22.17" at the top so it's installed *somewhere*

Comment: when I run `yarn build; gh-pages -d build` it works fine but if I run `yarn deploy` it doesn't... so that is weird for me and I don't know why it happens. Those are exactly the same commands I use but instead of writing `yarn build; gh-pages -d build` every time I just put them in new script and it doesn't work

Comment: It means the command line finds yarn but the npm process doesn't. I'll ask one last time: did you check the AppData folder mentioned in the error message?

Comment: Yes I did and in `/Roaming` folder I have only `Adobe` folder, nothing else. Oh I see now.. it is pointing to wrong folder, I have different one for that `/Roaming` folder. How can I fix that path?

Comment: In my Roaming folder there's an `npm` folder which contains `yarn`, `yarn.cmd` and `yarn.ps1`, among others. If you don't have any of that there's no chance of this working. What happens when you do `npm i -g yarn`?

Comment: The folder path is `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming`; this is a Windows path independent of node/npm where programs put their configurations and data files, etc. What do you mean "it is pointing to wrong folder"?

Comment: I mean this path which is in error is wrong. I think I need to change yarn path to be the correct one. I have 2 folders in `C>Users` folder and that is probably causing the issue here. Yarn is trying to find old one, I need to change it to new one where those files exists

Comment: In Users there's a `Public` folder and one for each Windows account. If you installed yarn in another account, it won't work. You have to install it for the user that is using the command. If you installed yarn in your admin account then logged back into your limited account, it won't work.

Comment: I have only one user but I think because it has special character in name some programs (and probably yarn also) have problem with installing it and they are automatically creating new folder with name without this special character and that is why I have 2 folders for the same account name

Comment: Yes, you absolutely shouldn't have special characters in your username. This is a common problem unfortunately and will cause all kinds of issues. Create a new Windows account without special characters and transfer everything over. It's also kind of funny that we could've solved this in five seconds if you hadn't pointlessly "censored" the screenshot ;P

Comment: Transferring over would take like a day probably... is there any fast way to do it?

Comment: Create the account and log in, then log back into your original account. Now copy everything from the old users folder into the new folder (including hidden files!), overwriting everything.

Comment: isn't there any way to rename it or something?

Comment: No, no chance, believe me, I would know. You can try this: https://superuser.com/a/1346983/886177 but it doesn't sound safe to me